# Using Pug with Visual Studio 2015 and Webpack

Tags: visual-studio, webpack, visual-studio-2015, pug-loader

I am relatively new to using Visual Studio but the project I am working on is a website with multiple pages in `.cshtml` files. I have set up Webpack as the front end build tool and want to start using [Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) as the templating engine. It makes more sense to me to have the build tool compile the Pug templates into HTML and keep my dependencies low, rather than Visual Studio compiling them (using something like [PugViewEngine](https://github.com/entith/PugViewEngine)).

Should I create a `/pug` folder and start re-building the views out there as `.pug` files with any Razor syntax as plain text - then use Webpack to compile to HTML with a `.cshtml` file extension and dump it back in the `/Views` folder of the Visual Studio project - or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: PugViewEngine wasn't an option in the end - broken and unmaintained repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by utilising [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin), [pug-loader](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader) and [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin).

1) Make sure to require the 2 plug-ins at the top of your `webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
```

2) Then have `html-webpack-plugin` reference your `index.pug` template in your `/src` folder:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.pug',
  })
]
```

3) Then have the `pug-loader` module handle your `.pug` files:

```
module:  {
 rules: [
   {
    test: /\.pug$/,
    use: 'pug-loader'
   }
 ]
}
```

4) Then use the `copy-webpack-plugin` to move the compiled HTML file from your `/dist` folder into the `/Views/` folder that Visual Studio will be refrencing. Change the filename to whatever you please and the file extension to `.cshtml`:

```
plugins: [
 new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
   from: 'dist/index.html',
   to: '../../Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml'
  }
 ])
]
```

5) Any razor syntax in your `.pug` templates you can treat as plain text with the `|` symbol:

```
| @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
```

There might be a cleaner way to do it but once set up it's pretty straightforward and works for my project now, as we transition to a cleaner front end process.